# Issue selecting an xpath when it is unknown if it will be on the page

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have this piece of selenium code I am trying to write, where it will select a page number indicator at the bottom of the page and count the elements on it.  However, this number indictor does not appear if there is only one page, and it will be updated in the future and eventually contain more than one page.

How can I make a piece of selenium code will select the last page if it finds that the page number indicator is there?  I have it search the webpage for a piece of text that only appears if the indictor appears, but I am stuck on what to do after that to make it select the last page in the page number indicator.

```
<div class="view view-blog view-id-blog view-display-id-page_1 view-dom-id-3e6e5f93bb52f8bc5f35e55c6da86526">
<div class="view-filters">
<form id="views-exposed-form-blog-page-1" class="views-exposed-form-blog-page-1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" action="/blogs">
</div>
<div class="view-content">
<div class="item-list">
</div>
<h2 class="element-invisible">Pages</h2>
<ul class="pager">
<li class="pager__item pager__item--current">1</li>
<li class="pager__item">
<li class="pager__item">
<li class="pager__item">
<li class="pager__item">    
<li class="pager__item">
<li class="pager__item pager__item--next">
<li class="pager__item pager__item--last">
```

`<li class="pager__item pager__item--last">` is the text that coressponds to the button I want to select.

In this there is 5 pages, so it would go to page 5, but I am trying to write it so that it just goes to the last page in the current list, so that I dont have to hardcode a number to jump to.

My current code is just

```
if (driver.getPageSource().contains("pager")) {
            WebElement k = driver.getPageSource().findElement("pager__item pager__item--last");
```

The `pager__item pager__item--last` is the string inside of the code that corresponds to the button I want to select `<li class="pager__item pager__item--last">`

What would be a good way to do this search for this string and then click on the button it corresponds to if you are unsure it even exists inside of your code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking Google search result as an example

1. Write a conditional statement for Page Number indicator
2. When the condition is satisfied, using FindElements method get all the `<a>` tags representing Page Numbers
3. Get the Last element from the list which will be the last page
4. Do a Click of element

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is using try catch..

```
try{
driver.findElementByXpath("Your xpath of last page button").click();//you can use any other locator
}catch(NoSuchElementException e){
//if you get exception then it means that element is not present(it means there is only one page)
//if you have multiple page then that button will be present and it'll not through any exception and it will trigger click event in that element and you'll get navigated to last page
}
```